# Wireless card causes ubuntu 12.04 to freeze on startup

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, atheros

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with a TP-Link TL-WN851ND wireless card. Every time I start up, anywhere between 0 and 60 seconds after the login screen appears, the computer freezes permanently and I am forced to power off. I managed to isolate the problem to the ath9k module, so I blacklisted ath9k and everything is running smoothly... Except now I can't use my wifi card.

Is there a way to fix ath9k? Or are there alternative drivers I can install?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

problem:
UB12.04 64-bit PC-Acer:
wifi worked normally, but recently not (dunno what upgrade/update did this)
after working for a day it freezes wifi connection and wifi button in top bar.

source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/148174/no-wifi-after-upgrading-12-04-kernel-to-3-2-0-24-generic-pae

solution:
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart

verified:
after command, wifi reconnecting and working.
dunno about tomorrow ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It happen because linux does not recognize the USB device if it is connected before the system is prepared to detect it. I have the same problem, and I couldn't get a complete solution.

What I have been doing is to start up the PC without the wireless card plugged on, and connect it when the cursor appears over the loading screen (the one with the ubuntu logo and the five circles).

*I'll be back when getting a better solution.*